# Область видимости переменной

Tags: переменные, sql-server

Здравствуйте.
Хотел произвести подсчет времени, затраченного на выполнение работы, но оказалось, что не так все просто, например:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DateTime = SYSDATETIME(); -- время начала работы
--GO --Делаю работу здесь, GO необходим
DECLARE @Seconds int = DATEDIFF(Second, @StartTime,SYSDATETIME()); --прошло секунд
SELECT GETDATE(),'Обновление=Успех сек='+CAST(@Seconds AS VARCHAR(8)) -- пишем результат
```

Выполнение кода вернет:

```
|   2013-03-25 15:55:33.740   |   Обновление=Успех сек=0    |
```

Но стоит раскомментировать --GO, так @StartTime пропадает из области видимости. *"Ошибка: Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную @StartTime"*

Как с этим бороться? (Помимо использования постоянных или временных таблиц)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В чем смысл делать GO? Проведем численный экперимент

```
DECLARE @StartTime DateTime = SYSDATETIME()

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
DECLARE @Seconds int = DATEDIFF(Second, @StartTime,SYSDATETIME())
SELECT GETDATE(),'Обновление=Успех сек='+CAST(@Seconds AS VARCHAR(8)) -- пишем результат
```

Comment: Ну я же ведь не просто так время считаю. Между началом и завершением необходимо направить несколько пакетов инструкций, включая очистку последующую выборку, заполнение таблиц. т.е. ресурсоемкие операции, а время пишу в лог.

Comment: А что именно в этих инструкциях обязывает вызывать GO? Я не могу придумать семантику где это необходимо

Comment: хм..., я использовал go после операции по очистке данных из каждой таблицы, перед тем как начать в нее писать. хотите сказать, что можно и не использовать. И еще разбитие большого пакета на несколько инструкций вселяло уверенность, что все будет выполнено постепенно и правильно.

Comment: Конечно можно. При желании можно обернуть в транзакции